# What does it mean when we say stationary states (i.e probability density is constant)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

When we talk about stationary states in Quantum Mechanics which have constant probability density, I understand the mathematical reason behind it about why they are stationary (time dependent variable cancels out) but what is the physical explanation of this, does this mean that probability density does not change at all with time (but that wouldn't make any sense as probability density will remain constant throughout time) or is there any other explanation?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/515796

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "that wouldn't make any sense as probability density will remain constant throughout time"?  Are you familiar with the fact that probability density does change with time for states that aren't energy eigenfunctions?